# Retrieve the response from the Rest API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I have the REST API which returns the JSON response like

```
[{
    "AccountID": "adm",
    "CounterSeq": "024",
    "Year": "17"
}]
```

I need to retrieve the response

```
 var response_EndPoint = await client_EndPoint.GetAsync(EndPoint_URL);
 var projectName = await response_EndPoint.Content.ReadAsAsync<APIResponseModel[]>();
```

The model class looks like

```
public class APIResponseModel
{
    public string AccountID { get; set; }
    public string CounterSeq { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

I need to construct the String which should be like "adm-024-17". How can I convert the response in the string?

Comment: I assume you are correctly getting a deserialized instance of `APIResponseModel` as your response?

Comment: Yes but I am not sure how to access the individual elements as the string

Comment: Add a toString() method to create the string you want from the data.

Comment: Typo alert: it's **retrieve**  - not "reterive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an instance of your `APIResponseModel` back from your service call, you just simply need to format the values into the string that you want:

Assuming, as it appears, it can come back as an array of `APIResponseModel` instances, then you just need to loop through the collection and format them as strings...

```
foreach(APIResponseModel response in projectName)
{
    string serviceResponse = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", response.AccountID, response.CounterSeq, response.Year);
    Console.WriteLine(serviceResponse);
}
```

Comment: If you're using c# 6.0 or later, you can also simplify that with `string serviceRseponse = $"{response.AccountID}-{response.CounterSeq}-{response.Year}`

Comment: Sure, that wasn't specified in the tags so I went with the most compatible way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a read only property to the class. This is assuming you have deserialized the JSON string.

```
public class APIResponseModel
{
    public string AccountID { get; set; }
    public string CounterSeq { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }

    public string getAllValues
    {
        get
        {
            return AccountID + "-" + CounterSeq + "-" + Year;
        }
    }

    // and/or

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AccountID + "-" + CounterSeq + "-" + Year;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be a function instead of a property, otherwise, yes - for the most part that is also a solution. I would also make it the `ToString()` function on that class for simplicity.

Comment: I agree with @gmiley. In fact, this would fit perfectly as a `ToString()` method.

Comment: That is also an option. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: The only downside to this solution is that if the OP doesn't own the service, and they are generating the class using the WSDL, if someone comes along in the future and makes changes and regenerates that class, they may never know that this was added and could lead to issues. Just something to keep in mind.